# "memory corruption" when following physics tutorial: how to fix?

Tags: c++, crash, runtime-error

I am just starting with Bullet and I have already run into difficulties with the first tutorial: http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World#Tutorial:_Hello_World_Application

My code compiles fine but it crashes when it reaches the line:

`dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher,broadphase,solver,collisionConfiguration);`

and I receive the error (if that's actually of any use...):

> malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000014fcc10

I have tried extensive searches on SO and on google but no one else seems to have this problem.

I'm using Ubuntu and Bullet 2.79.

**EDIT**
After further research, I found that a solution might be to add all the bullet source files directly.  However, this introduces a new problem: the compiler cannot find `vectormath/vmInclude.h` in the btSoftBodySolver_CPU.cpp file, even though it shows in the sources list.  Obviously, I can't tell if my previous error is fixed since compilation doesn't complete anymore.

Comment: That type of error usually means you've corrupted your heap sometime _before_ that call. (Usual suspect: writing outside the bounds of an array.) No-one can debug this for you without seeing the relevant code. Try to use `valgrind`.

Comment: That's something I hadn't considered.  I haven't actually used any arrays (this is just a test program to get Bullet linked and working) so I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.  I'll give Valgrind a go; Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "memory corruption" error at the same line of `HelloWorld.cpp`

For me, this was fixed by adding `-DBT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION=1` to my compilation command.

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved this.  Despite the error occurring at runtime, the problem was with how the library files were included.  By adding the directory of where the Bullet source was to the compiler, it now runs without any problems.